# Accessing items in lists within dictionary python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary that has keys associated with lists.

```
mydict = {'fruits': ['banana', 'apple', 'orange'],
         'vegetables': ['pepper', 'carrot'], 
         'cheese': ['swiss', 'cheddar', 'brie']}
```

What I want to do is use an if statement that if I search for item and its in any of the lists within the dictionary it will return the key. This is what I was trying:

```
item = cheddar
if item in mydict.values():
    print key
```

but it doesn't do anything, the output should be:

```
cheese
```

This seems like a simple thing but I just can't figure it out. Any help is awesome.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You'll have to use a `for`, a simple `if` is not enough to check an unknown set of lists:

```
for key in mydict.keys():
    if item in mydict[key]:
        print key
```

An approach without an explicit `for` statement would be possible like this:

```
foundItems = (key for key, vals in mydict.items() if item in vals)
```

which returns all keys which are associated with `item`. But internally, there's still some kind of iteration going on.

Comment: What if I want to "access" the list associated with each key, and turn it into a `temp_array` inside the for loop, for my own calculations? Let's say that I have to check something regarding the values of the list. In my case, the lists will contain integer numbers only.

Comment: @FrancescoCastellani depends on your actual use case; you could just access `mydict[key]` in any iteration, as in the first snippet; or you could do something like `map(mydict.values(), own_calculations)`.

Answer (score 4):

```
mydict = {'fruits': ['banana', 'apple', 'orange'],
     'vegetables': ['pepper', 'carrot'], 
     'cheese': ['swiss', 'cheddar', 'brie']}

item = "cheddar"

for key, values in mydict.iteritems():
    if item in values:
        print key
```

If you are going to do a lot of this kind of searching, I think you can create a reverse index for the original `mydict` to speed up querying:

```
reverse_index = {}

for k, values in mydict.iteritems():
     for v in values:
         reverse_index[v] = k

print reverse_index.get("cheddar")
print reverse_index.get("banana")
```

This way you don't have to traverse the `values` list every time to find an item.

Answer (score 3):

```
mydict = {'fruits': ['banana', 'apple', 'orange'],
     'vegetables': ['pepper', 'carrot'], 
     'cheese': ['swiss', 'cheddar', 'brie']}

item = "cheddar"
if item in mydict['cheese']:
    print ("true")
```

this works, but you have to reference the keys in the dictionary like cheese, vegetables etc instead because of the way you made the dictionary, hope this helps!