# Accessing lists inside a dictionary with Django Template tags

Tags: django, for-loop, django-templates

Bit stuck on how to access list values within a dictionary.

I've tried the following answers to no avail:

[Access Dictionary Value inside list in Django Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49609756/access-dictionary-value-inside-list-in-django-template)

[Accessing items in lists within dictionary python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11056757/accessing-items-in-lists-within-dictionary-python/11057115)

I am passing in through my view.py file the following:

```
context = {'checkoutList': CheckoutList, 'cartItems': cartItems}

return render(request, 'posts/checkout.html', context)
```

A queryset I am trying to access is Checkoutlist, and is as follows:

> {'id': [30, 6], 'title': ['Lorem Ipsum', 'another title'], 'location':
> ['Multiple Locations', 'city2'], 'imageurl': ['/media/image/img.jpg',
> '/media/image/img.jpg'], 'url': ['/products/lorem-ipsum',
> '/products/another-title']}

I am trying to access the list values in my Checkout.html page but I can't figure out how. Currently I can get the key and the entire list value, see below:

```
{% for key, value in checkoutList.items %}
    {{key}} {{value}}
{% endblock %}
```

This is returning the key values and the entire list, not the values inside the list.

```
id [30,6]
title ['Lorem Ipsum', 'another title']
etc..
```

What I am actually after is the values in the list on each for loop

```
first iteration 
30 lorem ipsum multiple locations

second iteration
6 another title city2
```

etc

How do I get the values like this?

Comment: can you show the code how are you creating **Checkoutlist**

Comment: this does the right thing. `id` IS the first key and `[30,6]` the first corresponding value. You could do ugly stuff like adding a `forloop.counter`, but it seems better to create the dictionary "more suitable"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pre-process the data in the view:

```
checkoutList = [
    {'id': id, 'title': title, 'location': location, 'imageurl': imageurl, 'url': url}
    for id, title, location, imageurl, url in zip(
        checkoutList['id'],
        checkoutList['title'],
        checkoutList['location'],
        checkoutList['imageurl'],
        checkoutList['url']
    )
]
```

then you can render this with:

```
{% for record in checkoutList %}
    {% for key, value in record.items %}
        {{key}} {{value}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```